# Determining the nature of common pH indicators (methyl orange) using Le Chatlier's principle

Tags: acid-base, equilibrium, ph, titration

I got some good information about this topic yesterday, and I understood what I was told, but I have come up with a specific way of phrasing the problem I'm having. It is slightly different than before, and I'm looking for someone to tell me if what I'm doing makes any sense or not, rather than just rote learning facts like 'methyl orange indicator is a weak acid/base'. I want to be able to use this process for any weakly acidic/basic indicator I come across.

(**Note:** Methyl orange is taken to be orange when it has a moderate pH (HIn, not very acidic or basic, and red between a pH of 4.4 and 3.1 - i.e. when it is In- or In+ depending on the scenario below)

*Assume* methyl orange, an indicator, is a weak acid. It dissociates as follows in aqueous solution;

[image: HIn is orange, In- is red]

We know that if an acid is added to this system at equilibrium, the concentration of hydrogen ions will increase. Using Le Chatlier's principle; to oppose this stress, the reaction shifts to the right, and the colour of the initial indicator (in this case methyl orange, so orange) will dominate and become more intense.

The solution will not go red, like it would if a base was added and proton concentration was decreased, as the equilibrium would shift in the other direction.

The problem is, that **if you add an acid to this system in real life, a colour change occurs at a pH of 4.4, from orange to red**. This means that methyl orange indicator cannot be an acid. Right?

If you *instead* assume that methyl orange is a weak base, it dissociates like so in aqueous solution;

[image: OHIn is orange, In+ is red]

So here, if you add an acid, the concentration of hydroxide ions will decrease (due to bonding between the hydrogen ions in the acid and these hydroxide ions to form water), so the equilibrium shifts to the right, to compensate.

This means that the red colour will dominate.

This result is in line with observation, as methyl indicator will change colour from orange to red at a pH of 3.1-4.4, which is acidic.

Does my reasoning therefore demonstrate that methyl indicator must be a weak base?

Comment: It's too broad, you could read many books acid/base properties of organic compounds

Comment: Ok. but surely for indicators where their properties (in terms of acid/base) are very relevant, there is some answer on this? For some reason phenolphthalein is defined as a 'weak acid' but Methyl Red/Orange can't be defined? How am I supposed to know how they dissociate in solution?

Comment: I've seen mechanisms for at least two first and imo it would be good to know them as they are interesting.

Comment: Methyl orange is weak base, their properties are well known. And if you want to know them you can check pKa or pKb+ values. You should edit your question - narrow it down.

Comment: According to my textbook and according to my state exam papers, methyl orange is a weak acid. According to another textbook I have, it is a weak base. There is no info either way I could find online. This is my point!

Comment: I don't think it is too broad. Did you have a look at any of the structures of the indicators you have mentioned? If you find controversial statements, include them in the post so that they can be cleared up. And since you have not done it yet, I invite you to take the [tour].

Answer (score 4):

[Methyl Orange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methyl_orange) is the common name for Sodium 4-[(4-dimethylamino)phenyldiazenyl]benzenesulfonate. So the compound is a *salt* or a conjugate base. It is the sodium salt for the indicator since that form is more soluble than the acid form.

[image]

The pKa is 3.47 in aqueous solution, so at pH values of 3.1 or lower the molecule is protonated.

[image]

At pH values greater than 4.4 all the molecules in solution are deprotonated as the sulfonate anion.

[image]

Linked two images from [ChemWiki](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Physical_Chemistry/Equilibria/Acid-Base_Equilibria/6._Acid-Base_Indicators).

---

The confusion is caused by rather poor wording in a question.
[image]

I'd prefer the wording to be:

> > > ... 
> > > In aqueous solution methyl orange indicator behaves like a weak acid. Letting HX represent the protonated form of the indicator, it dissociates as follows:

It is splitting hairs, but **methyl orange** is the name of the sodium salt, not the protonated form of the indicator.

Comment: So... if it is a conjugate base that means it dissociates like a base would in aqueous solution? (XOH ---> X+ and OH-)? I apologise for not using the correct terminology - I'm just beginning to understand what is involved in acid/base titrations

Comment: No, when the acid form loses a proton, then the anion is a conjugate base - it needs a proton to become neutrally charged. But the anion isn't an anion of "methyl orange" per se since methyl orange itself is a salt. // So this is analogous to acetic acid and sodium acetate.  In solution acetic acid is the protonated acid form, and acetate is the deprotonated anion form. The acetate anion is a conjugate base.

Comment: It doesn't get protonated on sulfonic group, which is least basic, but on N atom connected to the same ring as sulfonic group. This way most stable cation is created.

Comment: So, the acid is the one used as the indicator? I'm essentially trying to find out the properties of the indicator itself - not the conjugate base - so that I can know how it dissociates in aqueous solution. If indeed it is an acid, how can I explain what I've done above when I assume methyl orange to be an acid, then use Le Chatlier's Principle to effectively show that not to be true? Did I make a mistake?

Comment: @Mithoron - Thanks for the correction. I'll do some more research and fix the answer. I must have been brain dead. The amine group would be protonated in acid too. I'm surprised that the double bonded nitrogen group reacts.

Comment: @Malnurturedㅤㅤㅤㅤ Gee, it's the salt, which has basic anion

Comment: @Malnurturedㅤㅤㅤㅤ - Methyl orange itself can't be an acid since there isn't any proton to donate. Methyl orange is the name for the sodium salt, not the acid form.

Comment: @MaxW Great! Makes sense, that's what I thought except my exam papers (state level standardised tests, mind you) have this question where they call Methyl Orange an acid and have it dissociate like an acid: https://gyazo.com/086545c1acb65e7a2dd019c6d9c92984 What do you make of this? Just wrong?

Comment: @Malnurturedㅤㅤㅤㅤ - Someone made the same mistake I did, and didn't really check the chemistry. The wording seems a bit sloppy. I think "methyl orange indicator" would be better wording than "indicator methyl orange." Given the aqueous chemistry I doubt that 4-[(4-dimethylamino)phenyldiazenyl]benzenesulfonic acid exists as a solid. So the protonated form isn't really "methyl orange" per se.

Comment: @MaxW Gah, so there isn't really any way to tell whether they are talking about the conjugate base or the acid form unless they tell you (in terms of the exams I'm going to get at least). Sucks. Thanks man.

Comment: ?!? I have to wonder if the terminal amine group is protonated in weakly acidic solutions. The pKb for N,N-Dimethylaniline is  8.85. When the double bonded nitrogen protonates, then the hydrogen on the amine group would leave.

Comment: No there's quick equilibrating and azo protonated is strongly stabilised major form.

Comment: @ Mithoron - I guess a better way to put this is - I wonder what the ratio of the azo protonation to the amine protonation is as a function of pH. I looked and couldn't find anything on that. I'd guess that I just didn't know how to formulate the query. The ration has surely been evaluated.

Comment: let's continue in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3229/the-periodic-table)