Methyl orange resonance structure at different pH
I'm thinking about the changes in structures of methyl orange when the pH value changes. It's common to find that the azo group is protonated at pH values less than 3.1. Because of that, some resonances structures show adjacent conjugated double bond, and a $\lambda_{max}$ higher (a red colour in solution). Then, at pH values higher than 4.1, the conjugation disappears and the colour is yellow (the $\lambda_{max}$ is lower).
In other publications, though, I find that the azo group is unable to be protonated in water, and the protonated aromatic amine group has a pKa around 4.
How the protonation of the amine group could produce the necessary conjugation to produce a red colour in acidic media?

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/59682/is-methyl-orange-acidic-or-basic https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/42309/determining-the-nature-of-common-ph-indicators-methyl-orange-using-le-chatlier

Thanks @Mithoron, but that's exactly the problem. The protonation of the azo group seems to make no sense, because the presence of the more basic aromatic amine group in the same molecule.

Azo group is more basic than the amine. Draw the resonance structure to help you understand the electronic environment!

While normally azo groups may be less basic, in this case you get resonance stabilisation even from amino group.
